# Keeping first event between two ID groups in Stata

Tags: events, stata, panel

I am trying to keep the first event between two ID groups in Stata as well as the rest of the events.

```
ID1 ID2 Event Year
1    2    1   2021
1    2    1   2022
2    3    1   2021
2    3    1   2022
2    3    1   2023
```

I would like to see what initial events are correlated with and what subsequent events are correlated with. I am having a little difficulty with breaking the initial and subsequent events apart in Stata.

I used this command, but it is way off.

```
bys ID1 (ID2): gen first=_n if Event==1
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
clear 
input ID1 ID2 Event Year
1    2    1   2021
1    2    1   2022
2    3    1   2021
2    3    1   2022
2    3    1   2023
end 

bysort ID1 ID2 (Year) : gen byte is_first = _n == 1
```

The question asks about wanting to keep the first event -- but that evidently does not mean using the Stata command `keep` as you also want to keep subsequent events. So, I gather that you want an indicator variable for the first event.